# Nonuniform charge distribution: total charge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge

Can someone explain how the answer to part A is zero?
All of my attempts at the question result in a non-zero answer.
[image]

Comment: Did you integrate it from 0 to R.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\rho(r)$ is positive (assuming $\rho_0>0$) for $0<r<\frac34R$, and negative for $\frac34R<r\leq R$. So the integral from $0$ to $R$ contains both positive and negative contributions. Guess what it all adds up to (are you just having trouble with that integral?). Granted, that charge distribution's a little weird-looking, but that's what you're given.

**Edit replying to comment...**

Okay, I see your problem. You need the correct volume element in the integrand. At distance $r$ from the center, a shell has area $4\pi r^2$, and its thickness is $dr$ so its volume is (you guessed it:) $4\pi r^2dr$. So you need to integrate $Q=\int_0^R4\pi r^2\rho(r)dr$. Plug in your $\rho(r)$ and the answer indeed works out to $Q=0$.

I think you're saying you already tried that. Try it again. It works out trivially for me. I'll show you if you really need it, but I think you must just have made some simple blunder that you'll see yourself if you take another look.

Comment: What is the integrand of the integral? I tried [ρ(r)], [ρ(r)*(4pi r^2)] and [ρ(r)*(4/3 pi r^3)], all without luck.

Comment: Alright. I misinterpreted the definition of ρ(r). I read r/3R as (r/3)*R, but it's meant to be r/(3R). Just a quirk of order of operations, I suppose. Thanks though!

Comment: Great. (P.S. I **>>wasn't<<** the one who downvoted that **:**)

Comment: I don't mind the downvote, as long as I understand the problem in the end :)

Comment: By the way (better late than never), you could (maybe should) have seen that $r/3R$ >>must<< mean $\frac r{3R}$ and >>can't<< mean $rR/3$. Why??? Think about it a bit before continuing... Still thinking? Hint: dimensional analysis. Think some more before continuing... Your $\rho(r)$ >>must<< end up with units of $\mbox{Coulombs}/\mbox{cm}^3$, or something like that. And your $\rho_0$ is presumably already given in those units. So the stuff in $(\ldots)$ >>must<< be dimensionless. And $r/R$ is dimensionless, whereas $rR$ isn't. Dimensional arguments are frequently very simple and very powerful.